# How to update data using linq Query with joins and return number of rows effected in EF Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm new in using EF Core and Linq queries , I have a query in SQL Syntax want it to run as a LINQ query and return the no of rows that is effected by the update .

**SQL Query**

```
update BIV set BIV.IsActive = 0
            from
            Items I
            inner
            join ItemVariants IV on I.ItemID = IV.ItemID
            inner
            join BranchItemVariants BIV on BIV.ItemVariantID = IV.ItemVariantID
            inner
            join ItemCategories IC on I.ItemID = IC.ItemID
            Where IC.CategoryID = 11
            and BIV.BusinessBranchID = 5
```

Comment: You can do that only with EF Core 7 via `ExecuteUpdate`.

Comment: Is there any other way ? like if I use SP ?

Comment: SP or third party extensions. I can show sample with extension if you are interested in.

Comment: What if I use ExecuteSqlRaw function and pass the sql query ? will it work the same way

Comment: Yes, it should work. It also returns number of affected rows.

Comment: If performance it not important you can select them, set the field in a loop and save back.